# How to tell which static library the linker is using

Tags: linux, linker, static-libraries

I have built a static library in my home directory and there is also a copy of the same library elsewhere on the filesystem.  When building and linking I am interested in knowing which library it is linking against.  From what I understand once the linking is done there is no way to tell for static libraries.  I tried feeding the linker --verbose which strangely caused it to give full paths for some libraries but not others.

I am looking for a "which -llibraryname" command or a flag I can give the linker that would tell me the full path to a specific library.  The linker is ld invoked through gfortran.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `-Wl,-t` option. From `man ld`

```
   -t
   --trace
       Print the names of the input files as ld processes them.
```